# How to save table progress in postgresql between transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Tables are updating in loop, but if error come in one of table than transaction failed and all the tables data updated is gone so provide me the solution in which each time any table is update that its progress can save.

```
d0
$$
declare g record;
declare tablename varchar(50);
BEGIN
--fetching tablename from catalog.table
for g in execute formate ('select table_name from catalog.table');
loop
tablename= lower(g.tablename);
--passing tablename to function for some execution
execute'select function('''||tablename||''')';
end loop;

end;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction won't fail if you trap the error.

```
BEGIN
    execute your query
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation OR foreign_key_violation OR ... THEN

END;
```

When a function or codeblock is executed there is always already a transaction either created explicitly with a BEGIN or automatically. The BEGIN of the exception block acts as a SAVEPOINT in the transaction. When the error is trapped by the EXCEPTION part only the work after the BEGIN is lost because it rollsback to the savepoint.

When you let an error escape from the function a rollback of the whole transaction is done.

For details see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

BTW. postgresql 9.1 is not being maintained you should consider upgrading.

Comment: but how to save the table progress (means how to commit table between  transaction)

Comment: I have added explanation of how it works to the answer. You need to put an exception block like that inside your loop.